# Calculate a date from a given date

Tags: bash, shell, date, datediff

What I would like to do is to calculate the - let's call it - expected date from a given date and given a number.

I am looking for something like this

```
$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --date="10 days")
```

but I want to add +10 days from a given date and NOT from the current date.

I am sure that the answer will be probably simple, but at the moment I'm not able to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

I'll write it here hoping that will be useful for someone.

```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "$given_date+10days"
```